Tiktok client key
Developer application in tiktok app get me error
I follow the documentaion for link a tiktok account with my dev app
Here is the tiktok's doc

I get this error and I note that the client_key is the same as app client id

Anyone face this issue before
I try to figure out why the client code not working or how can I get the right client code of tiktok application

Tiktok gave me an error message which was hard to figure out. The error was in the redirect URL while it suggested me an error related to the client_key,
I changed the URL from https://example.com/auth/accounts to https://example.com/auth/accounts/
The URL must end with a /
